# UL LI tree, on the client part

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, razor

How can you build a ul LI tree based on an existing model? On the client side of the application.Nesting can be unlimited

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{

    <tr>
        <th scope="col">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id) </th>
        @if (item.ParentId != null)
        {
        <th scope="col">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ParentTitle) </th>
        }
        else
        {
             <th scope="col">null </th>
        }

        <th scope="col">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title) </th>
        <th scope="col">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description) </th>
        <th scope="col">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Created) </th>


    </tr>
}
```

I saw a manual build, just tagging and getting model elements, but is it possible to automate the process somehow?

```
<ul>
    <li>First parent
      <ul>
        <li>First child
          <ul>
```

Model:

```
[Table("TestTable", Schema = "dbo")]
    public class MyClass
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? ParentId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }


    public class MySecondClass
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? ParentId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string ParentTitle { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: depends what your model looks like

Comment: @Pete, MySecondClass, added to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have had a list of children property on your parent rather than 2 very similar classes, then you would be able to make a hierarchical structure:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public IEnuerable<MyClass> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Then instead of passing a flat set of classes through as your model, you can build up your hierarchy (in the below, I assumed Model is a list of all your items):

```
var topLevel = Model.Where(item => !item.HasValue); // or whatever the value is when there is no parent
```

Then  you can loop through this top level to set your children:

```
foreach (var item in topLevel)
{
    item.Children = GetChildren(item.Id, Model);
}
```

And your Get Children method can be

```
public static IEnumerable<MyClass> GetChildren(int parentId, IEnumerable<MyClass> allItems)
{
   if (parentId.HasValue)
   {
      var children = allItems.Where(item => item.ParentId.HasValue && item.ParentId.Value.Equals(parentId));
      if (children != null && children.Any())
      {
          foreach (var item in children)
          {
              item.Children = GetChildren(item.Id, allItems);
          }

          return children;
      }
   }

   return null;
}
```

This should help build something then you can have a partial that takes a model of `IEnumerable<MyClass>` and make it recursive:

```razor
@model IEnumerable<MyClass>

@foreach (MyClass item in Model)
{
    <ul>
        <li>
           @item.Title
           @if (item.Children != null && item.Children.Any())
           {
               @Html.Partial("NameOfThisPartial", item.Children)
           }
        </li>
    </ul>
}
```

And your initial partial call will be:

```
@Html.Partial("NameOfThisPartial", topLevel)
```

Comment: Would you mind a little more, I'm new to asp.net and it didn't work out.

Comment: I made some edits to above as I noticed I wasn't returning anything from my above  method.  All the c# stuff should be done when you are building your model (ie where your initial flat model was built) - so the model being passed to your page should only include the topLevel

Comment: TopLevel and do not understand the Foreach loop should be located in the Index?

Comment: the @foreach should be in your razor (in place of where you had your other @foreach) and your toplevel should be passed in place of where your other model was passed through

Comment: I'm totally confused.

Comment: I don't know how I can simplify this any further, if you do not understand the basics of the mvc models and razor / partials then there isn't a lot I can do for you as I was explaining from a place where you know what this all is.  Basically my foreach replaces your foreach, if it's not in a partial, make it as one and use it.  The c# bit replaces the bit where your existing model is built (but uses your existing model to create the new model - which is topLevel)

Comment: No no, I understand that @foreach is part of razor, but here's the var top level code where should I check this value? And recursion is more than understandable, I do not understand the mechanics in the GetChildren method, what, for example, is Model used there?

Comment: Model is your original code and I assumed it was the flat version of every item (`allItems`), if it is not, then all getChildren should do is get the children from wherever.  Also copy and paste error - see updated code.  Going home now but will answer any more questions when I get back tomorrow

Comment: everything turned out, thank you!I just misunderstood why you need a getchildren